# Should I Set pm.start_servers to Highest Value or Not?

Tags: ubuntu, logging, php-fpm

I have the following settings on my PHP-FPM:

```
pm.max_children = 256
pm.start_servers = 50
pm.min_spare_servers = 40
pm.max_spare_servers = 128
```

Even if I set it to higher value, I still get the following error:

```
[13-Dec-2013 11:58:55] WARNING: [pool web2] seems busy (you may need to increase pm.start_servers, or pm.min/max_spare_servers), spawning 8 children, there are 36 idle, and 58 total children
[13-Dec-2013 11:58:56] WARNING: [pool web2] seems busy (you may need to increase pm.start_servers, or pm.min/max_spare_servers), spawning 16 children, there are 32 idle, and 62 total children
[13-Dec-2013 11:59:12] WARNING: [pool web2] seems busy (you may need to increase pm.start_servers, or pm.min/max_spare_servers), spawning 8 children, there are 26 idle, and 77 total children
[13-Dec-2013 11:59:13] WARNING: [pool web2] seems busy (you may need to increase pm.start_servers, or pm.min/max_spare_servers), spawning 16 children, there are 27 idle, and 85 total children
```

I created a script that will reload the php5-fpm if the `pm.max_spare_servers` reaches 90. However, sometimes, before it reload the php5-fpm service, it already reaches the maximum spared server because I run the cron to check for that value every 15 minutes only.

So my question is what is the difference if I set the `start_servers` to lowest value instead of higher value.

Say something like:

```
pm.max_children = 256
pm.start_servers = 10
pm.min_spare_servers = 5
pm.max_spare_servers = 128
```

BTW, I'm using nginx and ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: As the message says, you need to _increase_ the value, not decrease it.

Comment: What I'm referring to is the `pm.start_servers`.

Comment: Sorry, the value you need to increase is `min_spare_servers`.